# Is this a known/named style guide?

Tags: citation-style

I am preparing a paper for publication and the journal requests that it is in the following style for references:

https://tandf.co.uk//journals/authors/style/reference/ref_ujrs.pdf

Is this a known style guide? It does not seem to match Chicago or APA.

Comment: Whether it is "known" or not, you will be required to use it I suspect.

Comment: Clearly. But if it is an existing style guide I can quickly reformat my citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference style seems to be called "Taylor & Francis Reference Style X Harvard" (TF-X Harvard).  A more detailed guide for it is at https://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/style/reference/tf_X.pdf .

Comment: There are some minor differences (e.g. the "Vol" and "No" syntax is missing), but this gets me quite close.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not notice that.  Taylor & Francis have a lot of reference styles (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reference+style+site%3Awww.tandf.co.uk&atb=v151-5__&ia=web) and I thought that the one in my answer was the one for the journal you are interested in (which I assume is the Canadian Journal of Remote Sensing).